# Information is required regarding .bat file

Tags: java, batch-file

I have one java project. I have to RUN on .bat before running the project. I am unable to understand or read its working structure.
As I open it in TextEditor, it shows text as below

```
@ECHO OFF

set bin=./bin
set classes=%bin%/cadel.jar;%bin%/clinkx.jar;%bin%/clink170b_ns.jar;%bin%/ns.jar
set main=org.itolab.morihit.cadel2.Cadel2
set rule=data/default

start /min "cadel" java -classpath %classes% %main% %rule%
```

It looks similar to me, but I cannot understand it completely.

How it is using "set" and why is it necessary to run my java project through bat file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` is the way .bat files define environment variables - here, in order to set up the classpath, the main class, etc.

It is not strictly required to run a java project via a .bat file, but considering the length of the command line required to run it (`java -classpath ... org.package.MainClass arg1 arg2 etc.`), it is simply more convenient.

Comment: One thing I observed. when I extracted the given .jar, that MAIN METHOD is getting values from RULE file, so how is it passing to main method 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
  if (args.length < 1) {
      usage();
    }

Comment: The relevant argument is `set rule=data/default`. I.e., the file you'd be using is `data/default`

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory. Set is used to define variables. It improves readibility, maintainance and reuse.